# Azure Analytics Query to see which ID has a StartTime before another ID's EndTime where the cloudRoleInstance is the same

Tags: azure-application-insights

Title says it all - I have App Insights Data that looks like this:

[image]

I need a query to go through this data and return to me - ID's 12345 and 09282 - because 09282 starts before 12345 and they are both on the same node.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use [join operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/joinoperator).

Sample code like below(assume the table name is mytable):

```
let mytablesss = mytable 
| where timestamp > ago(7d);
mytablesss
| join kind= inner (  
   mytable
   | where timestamp > ago(7d)  
) on cloudRoleInstance
| where StartTime < EndTime1

//if startTime and EndTime are string type, use todatetime(StartTime) and todatetime(EndTime1) in the where clause.
```

Please feel free to modify the code to meet your need.

Note that: in the 2nd table(mytable), all the fields will be automatically suffix with 1, eg. in the first table, the filed is Endtime; but in the 2nd table, it becomes Endtime1.